# C# - Query about using an Edit button to update a record from a DataGrid

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datagridview, sql-update

I have a WinForms application, and I'm using a Search function to look up DB records on a DataGrid on C#. Once a record is searched and found, I have an Edit button implemented, in order to edit / update that specific record.

With that said, I don't know (sorry, coding newbie) how to implement this, since I would need to 'call' what I searched on the Search Form, in order to edit it on the Edit Form. Please let me know if any code is required.

Comment: If you are using ADO.Net instead of something like EntityFramework, you can [look at this example I prepared for questions like this](https://github.com/crowcoder/CSharpCrudGrid)